# Target aot_assembly_release failed: Exception: release/profile builds are only supported for physical devices. attempted to build for simulator

Tags: flutter, xcode, ios-simulator

I am new to Flutter iOS Development. I was trying to run my flutter app with three flavors dev, stage and prod. After running the application I am getting the following error.

```
Error (Xcode): Target aot_assembly_release failed: Exception: release/profile
builds are only supported for physical devices. attempted to build for
simulator.


Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 14 Pro Max.
```

I have searched a lot, but haven't got any solutions over internet. It would be helpful if anyone will be able to help me with it.

PS - I want to run it on Simulator only. Thank You.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have the same issue. It works on physical devices, just not on simulator. Code doesn't really help here.

Comment: Your problem has probably been resolved by now but for anyone else I want to suggest restarting your computer. No trying to make a joke, I had a similar issue twice and restarting resolved it.

Answer (score 5):

When you build on the simulator. The debug mode for the scheme is unique. If use release mode, the issue above will appear.
[image]

Comment: how to solve this?

Comment: @irufano Product -> Edit Scheme -> Build Configuration: Release-development

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer of "Cao Anh Dung".

you need to make sure that youre using debug config here

[image]